# How to make a player class that holds lives.(inheritance)

Tags: java

Im trying to make a player class that has 10 lives and has a damage method and a checkDeath method the The damage method takes on life away from the player and the check death method should check if the player is dead by seeing if the player has less than one life left an return true if the player is dead or false.

This is my code so far:

```
public class Player {
    protected boolean death = true;
    Player mylife= new Player();//Dont know how to assign it 10 lives

public void damage(){
    if (myLife < 1) {
               return true;
            else { 
            return false;

}
public void checkDeath() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Player {
    int liveCount = 10;

    public boolean damage() {
        if (myLife < 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean isDead() {
         return liveCount < 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Player {
  int liveCount = 10;

  public boolean damage() {
    --liveCount;
    return isDead();
  }

  public boolean isDead() {
     return liveCount < 1;
  }

  public void boostLives(int moreLives) {
    liveCount += moreLives;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Player{
    int lives=10;
    public boolean damage(){
      lives--;
      return isDead();
    }
    public boolean isDead(){
      return lives<1;
    }
```